# Отключить авторизацию для одного файла на сервере

Tags: php, apache, ldap

Сайт на php с авторизацией LDAP, apache. Возникла необходимость дать беспарольный доступ к единственному из его файлов (ну или хотя бы к директории), находится по пути /var/www/html/rdb/map.php
ничего не удалось найти

Comment: Авторизация LDAP на директорию не ставится. Скорее всего из LDAP приходят пользователи, а сама авторизация уже смотрит можно/нельзя. Можно уточнить тип авторизации, наверное можно увидеть в заголовках HTTP или в коде. Если есть встплывашка при отказе, то точно - Bascic.

Еще нужна информация о сервере - nginx или Apache?

Comment: Да, всплывашка есть. Сервер apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервер - Apche и авторизация - Basic, то можно сделать в *.htaccess*:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
<Files "map.php">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Начиная с Apache 2.4 можно использовать *Require*:

```
<Files "thubservice.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Только нужно точно знать, что .htaccess обрабатывается
По моему блоки можно разбавить. Например, если Auth-директивы уже прописаны для корня сайта, то блок Files можно разместить в отдельном *.htaccess* в директории */rdb/*